# in guice,how to inject an object of generic type?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, guice

in guice,how to inject an object of generic type ?
for examle:

```
class Person{
   Map sons;
}
```

how to inject a Map constructured HashMap ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either just use the raw type in Guice or use the Named annotation.